# Click method not working - using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape data from the public site.
On the search page enter the search value and press the view button (normal submit)its shows the results.

normal browser view button clicks and shows the report as expected. but when I try to click the same button via the Webdriver code, the button clicks but the result was not shown.

Can anyone face this issue?

I tried the button click using XPath(`//*[@id="b-form-submit"]/div/button`) with the below method

```
Click()
Submit()
Click using Javascript
Click using action class (keyboard event)
```

Button HTML code

```
<div class="b-button" id="b-form-submit">
   <div class="b-button-container">
      <span class="left">
      <i></i>
      </span>
      <button alt="View" type="submit">View</button>
      <span class="right">
      <i></i>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

When i try to click the view button manually from the webdriver (debug mode) its not wokring, but same its working normal web browser (all the browsers)

Comment: Is your webpage publicly available? It might be possible website is blocking web scraping.

Comment: @KunduK - Yes it's a public webpage. How it's possible to block the web scraping? I can able to navigate the webpage thru the URL and able to enter the search value also

Comment: Could you [Edit] your post and update the url so that other contributor can help you.

Comment: @KunduK - Sorry due to security reasons I couldn't share the URL.

Comment: Try with explicit wait and check whether it works. `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='View']"))).click();`

Comment: @KunduK - Yes I used the wait statement but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

The `<button>` isn't an immediate descendant of the `<div>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)::

- `css_selectors`:

  ```
  div#b-form-submit>div button[alt='View']
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  //div[@id="b-form-submit"]/div//button[@alt='View' and text()='View']
  ```

---

So to `click()` on the element with text as **View** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#b-form-submit>div button[alt='View']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id="b-form-submit"]/div//button[@alt='View' and text()='View']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#b-form-submit>div button[alt='View']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id="b-form-submit"]/div//button[@alt='View' and text()='View']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I'm not getting any exception with my XPath, and your XPath also correct. and I open the driver EXE load the webpage manually in that driver and click the view button it does not show the results, at the same time I can enter a search value.

Comment: @Prabu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: There are no issues in the XPath. The Button clicked in the driver, but not produce the result, I think that site blocked the search result via Driver execution.

Comment: @Prabu We aren't aware about the site and not sure if the bot is detected. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Please refer to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65774494/data-scraping-using-selenium-unable-to-find-the-search-result

Comment: did you go through my question, do you have any solution?