# Data Scraping using selenium unable to find the search result

Tags: javascript, java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

we are going to scrape data from the below site
https://ras.arbitr.ru

Step:

1.Load the webpage

2.Click the View button [Left panel]

3.To verify the search result loaded in the right-side panel or not?

Normal click from the web browser's working perfectly, when I try to click from the web driver it's not loading the result.

I'm using the below attributes to click the view button

```
using the ID
Using button caption
Using CSS selector
Click using Javascript
Using Keyboard event
```

Code:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://ras.arbitr.ru/')
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
WebElement viewButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#b-form-submit>div button[alt='Найти']"))
viewButton.click()
//viewButton -//*[@id="b-form-submit"]/div/button
//viewButton - "//button[contains(text(),'Найти')]"
```

from the web driver click event-triggered but the search result not showing on the right-side panel.

It's perfectly working to do the same steps in web browsers.

Comment: Could you provide code examples and a example website where the code does work?

Comment: @JamesWebb Added my code.

Comment: Thank you. I'd check that the cssSelector you have is definately getting the button you expect (and only one of them, not multiple). If that is working I'd then try opening the console in the browser, trying to select the element and calling .click() on it. This might help give more insight into the problem.